# Permutation of n elements between multiple layers/groups

Tags: python, math, permutation, combinatorics

I honestly lack the knowledge to figure this out for a while now. It is less of a "coding" and more of a "mathematical" problem, bit of context beforehand:

There is a 2D map with n_d drivers and n_p passengers. The goal is to find the most optimal set of routes for drivers carrying passengers, most optimal route set is one that covers the least vector length in total for all drivers. Driver entities have a starting position, whereas passenger entities have a desired start and end position for their travel.

My idea is to simply iterate through all possible routes and give a score. So far I understand how I would do that for one driver and n_p passengers - do a permutation of all passenger routes, calculate total distance traveled, and we have the winner.
I know it is a very inefficient approach, but my plan is to implement filters to discard useless permutations and boost processing speed.

The problem comes with permutation between multiple drivers. I just cannot understand how to do permutation of all n_p passengers between all n_d drivers.

This is how a problem looks on a 2D chart. Black arrows are desired passenger routes, green dots are drivers.

[2D map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBpzl.png)

Here's one possible permutation of 8 passengers split between 4 drivers. Solution does not know how much drivers and passengers there are, should work for any numbers.

[illustration of one permutation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CATuO.jpg)

An explanation or pseudo-code mock up (preferably Python) would help a lot, or maybe there is a term for this problem in combinatorics that I just do not know, thank you!

Comment: I do not know the answer, but one thing that comes to mind is you probably want to minimize 'useless' distance where a driver is driving from the end-point of one route to the starting of another. I think that if you pair each passenger end point with another start point you will eventually generate a cycle that has all of the routes taken care of. From there I guess you could divide your full cycle amongst your drivers to remove the largest of the gaps. Since time isn't an issue you don't need even workloads amongst drivers ... so you should aim to sort by largest gap and delete those?

Comment: You won't be able to find *the* best solution by trying them all as soon as the number of passengers/drivers gets large. This is a more complicated version of the travelling salesman problem, and it's already impossible to try all possibilities in reasonable time for less than 20 cities. You could have a look at some heuristic methods used for that problem to find "good" solutions.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions to try and simplify the original problem, it is not always that simple though which is why question remains open. The complexity that the system may face is unknown and it could be that complex permutations are a reasonable solution, even if they take a lot of resources it may be justifiable.

Comment: I am unsure of the point of the multiple drivers if you are not going to simply use them to only delete the largest gaps in the path. if you are not doing that it implies there is more to the problem then you have written, unless there is something I am missing.

As Thierry Lathuille suggested, this seems to be the travelling salesman problem.

Comment: Multiple drivers provide the opportunity to minimize total travel distance. Imagine one driver for a whole city - they will travel a bigger total distance, rather than 3 drivers that can carry out routes in multiple regions. It is still a question whether routes dictate driver count, or driver count dictates routes. I just cannot explain all nuances in one question, I purposely simplified this problem to a combinatorics question, otherwise no one would be able to answer. Even the simplified question is hard to answer.

Comment: this question needs some code.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I re-read the question just now, I understand what you are asking better. My prior comments makes no sense in light of what I now understand you to be asking

Comment: Thank you for your answers, the conclusion is really that permutation is too insane of an approach for this problem and other ways should be investigated.